# Mapbox GL - Add polygon which does not scale while zooming

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

Is there a way to add a polygon which stays the same size during the zoom action?

Currently if you add the polygon circle shape within the radius of 10 meters, when you zoom out, the polygon will get smaller which is correct functionality, but is it possible to add that shape which does not scale within the map and keeps the size no matter the zoom value?

From the documentation I cant find anything. If I create the polygon it always keeps scaling. I cant even find a way to resize manually like we can for the circles on zoom action.

Comment: Is there any solution, my requirement is also bit same, I want to draw a line and that shouldn't change the length when zooming in or zooming out ?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just create a marker where the marker image is a polygon shape.